# Azure Deploy: No Worker assigned to App Service Plan. Site Cannot Serve any requests. How To?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, web-worker

I'm trying to deploy my solution to Azure so my website can be accessed through the Internet.
When I deploy, Azure DevOps tells me Release/Deploy succeeds, but when I open the azurewebsties.net-URL, I get a 404.

After running some diagnostics, it tells me:

```
Currently no worker is assigned to the app service plan. The site cannot serve any requests.
```

[image]

When I research on how to Add a worker I find this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-app-service-add-worker-roles?view=azs-2008&tabs=azurerm

But when I try and follow it, my azure interface is too different from theirs, and things don't add up. It says:

```
Azure App Service on Azure Stack Hub supports free and shared worker tiers by default.
```

I don't see any worker tiers at all, the tutorial-mentioned tab Roles, deals with userPermissions.

JSON resource seem to show there are no workers indeed.
But diagnostics also says following information is logged by... a worker.

Though I cannot exclude problems elsewhere for a 100%, It really seems to be a worker-problem.
Build- & ReleasePipeline succeed, Artifact get uploaded & deployed, Authentication & KeyVault is good, I get Request&Response Activity in AzurePortal-Graphs. But no website.

So my questions are:

1. What are these workers, what do they do high-level? Operate like some kind of ServiceBus between WebApp & Azure? What language/format are they in?
2. How and where can I add one? Is it in code (angular/c#), JSON or in azure portal?
3. Where can I find *up to date* documentation

Anybody know how to tackle this?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The documentation you have linked relates to Azure Stack, could you please clarify whether you are trying to use an Azure Stack implementation or "normal" Azure? If standard Azure, you shouldn't have to do anything to do with workers to make an app service plan work, so this looks like a provisioning error on their side.

Comment: Could you also please specify exactly how you created the app service and app service plan?

Comment: @Tom W I'm trying to use a 'normal' Azure :) If I recollect correctly, after I made my Azure-Account I first Added a Service Plan, then the App Service (Azure SQL-Db, SignalR, KeyVault, etc)I had to specify which AppService Plan I wanted to use for said services, seeing as my ServicePlan was the only option, I just rolled with it like thatI did everything in Azure portal if thats what you mean? Thanks for enquiring! Everyting is centralised in 1 resource-group

Comment: @TomW Could it have something to do with Angular2 RegistrationStrategy you think?

Comment: @TomW Or could it be because I have no Storage accounts on Azure?

Comment: Possibly some misconfiguration that crashes the hosting process on startup could be at fault, as on the Free tier the hosting logic (probably?) won't be willing to spawn new processes for your application at an arbitrary frequency, so that _might_ manifest as no worker assigned, maybe? Do you get the same behaviour with a brand new application with no custom logic on the same app service? Are you paying for your subscription or restricted to free resources; could you scale up the app service plan to a higher tier?

Comment: @TomW I'm indeed in the Free tier atm. I remember from 1,5 years ago it should be possible on free tier though, but you could be right seeing as Azure is constantly changing :) Right now i'm investigating if the problem lies with my Angular Deployment or Server Config, it's something I had not looked into before so I am following https://angular.io/guide/deployment and see what happens. Will try your suggestion of scaling up if the angular deployment doens't help me. Will get back to you with updates! Thanks for helping me find a solution!

Comment: For other readers: Should be possible with the Free Trial/Tier subscription/plan

Comment: @BHANG do you figure it out?

Comment: @IvanYang I'm not completely through all problems, but I had to configure my service connection in azure devops => projects => service connection. Make it point to your azure subscription & resource group. Now I do have a service worker assigned. Still getting 404's thou ;-)